# Lit element (typescript) not re-rendering when property changes due to window resize

Tags: typescript, window-resize, lit-element, rerender

I am displaying card images based on the width of the window (and also based on other elements present in the UI). When the window resize event is triggered, the re-computation is happening properly but the updated properties not re-rendered.
Just to test out, I added a dummy button and after resizing the window, called the same re-compute function on click. This however is triggering a re-render properly.
Adding the code below:

```
import {LitElement, html, customElement, property} from 'lit-element';

@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {

    @property({type: Number})  computedNumCards: number = 0;
    @property({type: Array})  dummyCards: Array<any> = [];

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.computedNumCards = 0;
        this.dummyCards = [];
   }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.init();
        this.computeNumCards() 
    }  
    
    computeNumCards() {
        let cardWidth = 320;
        let pageWidth = window.innerWidth;
        //some more computation here, simplifying as its not relevant for this question
        this.computedNumCards = Math.floor((pageWidth / cardWidth));
        this.dummyCards = Array(this.computedNumCards).fill(html`<span> <img src="card.png"/></span>`);
        console.log(pageWidth);
    }

    init() {
        let self = this;
        window.onresize = function(){
         setTimeout(self.computeNumCards, 1000);
        };
    }
    //on adding the dummy button below and clicking it after re-sizing the window, the cards are re-rendered properly

    render() {
        return html`
            <div class="container">
                <button id="1" @click="${() => this.computeNumCards()}" aria-label="computeCards">-</button>
                <p>${this.computedNumCards}</p>
               
                ${this.computedNumCards && this.computedNumCards > 0?  this.dummyCards.map(dummyCard => {
                    return dummyCard
                }) : html``}
                </div>
         
        `;
    }
}
```

Comment: after `setTimeOut`., have you tried adding `self.requestUpdate()`. It re-renders DOM. Check lit-Element licfecycle menthods here https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#requestupdate

Comment: Yes I had tried that too in the end of computeNumCards. Even this is not helping. I have this same component (with different parameters) present 2-3times in the UI. The last one is getting reflected correctly on window resize, but the remaining ones don't change. I even tried removing the setTimeout completely and called computeNumCards directly.

Answer (score 0):

When the `onresize` callback triggers, `this` inside of `computeNumCards` is `Window` not the instance of `MyComponent`. So you are setting the new properties on `Window` not the component. If you use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) the context will be correct and then the component state will be set triggering a render.

```js
init() {
  window.onresize = () => {
    setTimeout(() => this.computeNumCards(), 1000);
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi Abraham, thanks for the suggestion. I made the changes you suggested but this looks same to what I am doing already. I am passing the "this" reference by storing it in "self" in the last line so that is not a problem. I agree using arrow functions is better syntactically, and I have incorporated that change but it din't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using window.onresize, window.addEventListener solved the issue.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => setTimeout(() => this.computeNumCards(), 100));
```